# Visible attribute undefined for multiple modals

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am trying to include 2-3 modals in my single page application. But I am having trouble making all of them work at the same time. My first modal works properly, but my second and third Modal fails to $watch the visible attribute.

These are my modal toggle functions:

```
$scope.toggleModal = function(){
    $scope.showModal = !$scope.showModal;
};

$scope.toggleTestModal = function(){
    $scope.showTestModal = !$scope.showTestModal;};

$scope.toggleBranchSelectModal = function(){
  $scope.showBranchSelectModal = !$scope.showBranchSelectModal;
  console.log('$scope.showBranchSelectModal', $scope.showBranchSelectModal);
};
```

These are my directive for these three modals:

**Modal 1**

```
cicdapp.directive('modal', function () {
return {
  template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
      '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
        '<div class="modal-content">' +
          '<div class="modal-header">' +
            '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
            '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>' +
    '</div>',
  restrict: 'E',
  transclude: true,
  replace:true,
  scope:true,
  link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
    scope.title = attrs.title;

    scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
      console.log(value)
      if(value == true)
        $(element).modal('show');
      else
        $(element).modal('hide');
    });

    $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
      });
    });

    $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
      scope.$apply(function(){
        scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
      });
    });
  }
};
});
```

**Modal 2**

```
cicdapp.directive('testmodal', function () {
console.log('Test modal')
  return {
    template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
          '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
              '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace:true,
    scope:true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.title = attrs.title;

      scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
        console.log(value)
        if(value == true)
          $(element).modal('show');
        else
          $(element).modal('hide');
      });

      $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
        });
      });

      $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;});});}};});
```

***Modal 3***

```
cicdapp.directive('branchselectmodal', function () {
  return {
    template: '<div class="modal fade">' +
        '<div class="modal-dialog">' +
          '<div class="modal-content">' +
            '<div class="modal-header">' +
              '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>' +
              '<h4 class="modal-title">{{ title }}</h4>' +
            '</div>' +
            '<div class="modal-body" ng-transclude></div>' +
          '</div>' +
        '</div>' +
      '</div>',
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    replace:true,
    scope:true,
    link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.title = attrs.title;

      scope.$watch(attrs.visible, function(value){
        if(value == true)
          $(element).modal('show');
        else
          $(element).modal('hide');
      });

      $(element).on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = true;
        });
      });

      $(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
        scope.$apply(function(){
          scope.$parent[attrs.visible] = false;
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

When I toggle the modals, through I logging I figured that inside $watch for attrs.visible, its value is undefined for Modal 2 and 3, while it works as expected for Modal 1. I am trying to think why this is happening, but I cannot think of a reason why this should work in the first case and not in the other two. Any direction on why this is happening would be appreciated.

Comment: I think you need refactor your code firstly. Why you need even 3 directive which almost different in template while you can pass it as parameter with one directive ? Also you should not access to parent scope's value in the directive? use scope property alternatively. Look some other dialogs ready-to-use: ngDialog, bootstrap modal...?

Comment: Ok, made all those change. I still have the same exact issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the responses you've gotten so far, it sounds like you've since refactored your code somewhat. I would recommend one directive for a modal to which you give each instance different content (since you're transcluding content anyway), and the directive should use an isolate scope. It's a modal dialog, so it should be treated as a completely separate entity. It should never try to reach up into its parent. Upon clicking "close", "cancel", "OK", or whatever button dismissed the modal, that should emit (not broadcast) an event which the container should listen for, and then it should dismiss the modal (i.e. the modal should not dismiss itself, or "self-destruct").